# Toggling text wrap in a JTextpane

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextpane

How would I go about toggling text wrap on a `JTextpane`?

```
public JFrame mainjFrame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
    public JTextPane mainJTextPane = new JTextPane();
        public JScrollPane mainJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainJTextPane);
        mainjFrame.add(mainJScrollPane);
```

Comment: If you don't want wrapping why don't you use JTextField ?

Comment: @Stefanos Kalantzis I don't believe JTextField provides as many styling abilities as JTextpane.

Comment: As `JTextField` is a single-line text component, word wrap does not make sense there. You probably mean `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 11):

See [No Wrap Text Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/).

Edit:

Well, if you want to toggle the behaviour, then you would also need to toggle the getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() value. See [Scrollable Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/). You should be able to toggle between FIT and STRETCH.

Comment: +1 for a very good answer that worked; however I am trying to toggle the text wrapping, and have updated the question. Sorry for the bad question.

Answer (score 10):

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class TestVisual extends JFrame {

    private boolean wrapped;
    private JButton toggleButton = null;
    private JTextPane textPane = null;
    private JPanel noWrapPanel = null;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = null;

    public TestVisual() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        wrapped = false;

        textPane = new JTextPane();
        noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        noWrapPanel.add( textPane );

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane( noWrapPanel );

        toggleButton = new JButton("wrap");
        toggleButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                if (wrapped == true){
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(noWrapPanel);
                    noWrapPanel.add(textPane);
                    toggleButton.setText("wrap");
                    wrapped = false;
                }else {
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(textPane);
                    toggleButton.setText("unWrap");
                    wrapped = true;
                }
            }
        });

        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(toggleButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

I don't know any other way for what you are looking for..

But this is working well.

( Based on camickr's answer.. +1 )

Comment: you can replace the first 5 imports with "import javax.swing.*;
"

Comment: I used eclipse fix imports. :)